# Managed code in a hosted .NET Core runtime corrupts the caller stack

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, stack-corruption, .net-runtime

I am playing with the [.NET Core runtime hosting example](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/master/core/hosting/HostWithCoreClrHost).

When I build it "as is" (64 bit) on Windows, it works.

When I build it as a 32-bit application (on Windows) and change the .NET runtime to x86 (`-r win-x86`), it crashes.

This is what's happening. After the `managedDelegate` returns, the stack of the caller (`main()`) is corrupted and the app crashes.

```
doWork_ptr managedDelegate;

createManagedDelegate(
        hostHandle,
        domainId,
        "ManagedLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0",
        "ManagedLibrary.ManagedWorker",
        "DoWork",
        (void**)&managedDelegate);

char* ret = managedDelegate("Test job", 5, sizeof(data) / sizeof(double), data, ReportProgressCallback);
```

When I change the managed method (`DoWork`) to a `void`-returning one without any parameters, it works.

It seems that I am missing something about the calling conventions, but cannot spot what exactly. The default one is `stdcall` on Windows, but there are some differences between x86 and x64 too. x64 uses a special `x64 fastcall` convention, and I suspect it somehow messes up the whole thing when hosting the .NET CLR in a 32-bit app.

What do I need to change to get this running? Do I need to build the native (host) app using a specific calling convention? Do I need to decorate the managed methods with special attributes? Or maybe somehow configure the hosted .NET Core runtime?

Comment: Yes, they cut corners on that sample, clearly intending it to only ever be used with the x64 runtime.  Which is pretty normal for .NETCore, why they ever decided to support x86 is a bit of a mystery.  Probably too much work to remove it.  The declaration of the function pointers is critical, for x86 you get to deal with [incompatible calling conventions](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/9970).  There is no distinction between cdecl and stdcall in x64.  More macro soup needed, the Windows declaration would be `typedef int (__stdcall *report_callback_ptr)(int progress);`, etc.

Comment: @HansPassant There are 32-bit machines out there still, e.g. Acer Aspire Switch 10

Comment: I'll pass, they shoot the messenger around here and I really have no idea why they coded the sample this way.  Just share what you discovered in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @HansPassant mentioned in the comments:

> The declaration of the function pointers is critical, for x86 you get to deal with incompatible calling conventions. There is no distinction between `cdecl` and `stdcall` in x64. More macro soup needed, the Windows declaration would be `typedef int (__stdcall *report_callback_ptr)(int progress);`, etc.

That is the trick.

The callback and the managed method function pointer need to be additionally decorated with the `__stdcall` attribute:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *report_callback_ptr)(int progress);
typedef char* (__stdcall *doWork_ptr)(const char* jobName, int iterations, int dataSize, double* data, report_callback_ptr callbackFunction);
```

The callback implementation needs to be decorated too:

```
int __stdcall ReportProgressCallback(int progress) { /* implementation here */ }
```

It turns out that the managed marshaler treats the managed methods as `__stdcall` on x86, which is no surprise.

Applying those changes makes the sample work when built as an x86 app hosting the x86 .NET Core runtime.